# WPF Set attributes back after a event is finished

Tags: c#, wpf

so what i would like to is setting back some attributes after an Custom Event is finished.

Scenario i have a save BackupDrives Class that does collection of data and then offers a Event to be called after its done.

Changing object properties can be done by button click, what i would like is to set them back to the same value after the event is finished.

Button click does the thing :

```
private void bbdrives_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {  
        backup.SaveDrives += OnSavingDrives;
        backup.DrivesSave();
        Drive_text.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        drives_progres.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        drives_progres.IsIndeterminate = true;
    }
```

Now the triggered event method is not able to change the properties back.

```
private void OnSavingDrives(object sender, DrivesEventArgs e)
    {
       
        Directory.CreateDirectory(....);
        File.WriteAllLines(e.Something, e.List2ToSave);
        File.WriteAllLines(e.Something_lse, e.List1ToSave);

        Drive_text.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        drives_progres.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        drives_progres.IsIndeterminate = false;
    }
```

How do i do this. Since this does not work.

And on other thig here to - when i run the GUI i need to click 2 times one the same button to start it all. Done Code Clean + Rebuild. Still the same.

---EDIT---

As for code here you go.

This is a Class for collecting method and event.

```
public class DrivesEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    string MYDOC = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    const string backup_Drives = "....";
    const string backup_Letters = "...";
    public List<string> List1ToSave = new List<string>();
    public List<string> List2ToSave = new List<string>();

    public string SAVE_DRIVE_Letter
    {
        get
        {
            string name = Path.Combine(MYDOC, backup_Letters);
            return name;
        }
    }
    public string SAVE_DRIVE_Path
    {
        get
        {
            string name = Path.Combine(MYDOC, backup_Drives);
            return name;
        }
    }
}
public class DrivesBackup
{

    private const string path = "Network";
    private List<string> drives_to_save = new List<string>();
    private List<string> letters_for_drives = new List<string>();
    private RegistryKey reg1, reg2;
    public event EventHandler<DrivesEventArgs> SaveDrives;
    public void DrivesSave()
    {
        var data = new DrivesEventArgs();
        try
        {
            if (drives_to_save.Count == 0)
            {
                reg1 = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(path);
                string[] mounted_drives = reg1.GetSubKeyNames();

                foreach (var drive in mounted_drives)
                {   //get all UNC Paths from mounted_drives

                    string[] getUNC = { path, drive };
                    string fullUNC = Path.Combine(getUNC);
                    reg2 = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(fullUNC);
                    string UNCPath = reg2.GetValue("RemotePath").ToString();  //getting UNC PATH
                    Console.WriteLine(UNCPath);

                    data.List1ToSave.Add(drive.ToString());
                    data.List2ToSave.Add(UNCPath);
                    OnSaveDrives(data);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {

            throw er;
        }


        
    }

    protected virtual void OnSaveDrives(DrivesEventArgs eD)
    {
        SaveDrives?.Invoke(this, eD);
    }
```

Now here is the MAINWINDOW WPF

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    DrivesBackup backup = new DrivesBackup();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void bbdrives_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {  
        backup.DrivesSave();
        backup.SaveDrives += OnSavingDrives;
        Drive_text.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        drives_progres.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        drives_progres.IsIndeterminate = true;
    }

 private void OnSavingDrives(object sender, DrivesEventArgs e)
    {
       
        Directory.CreateDirectory(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), @"SEG-Backup"));
        File.WriteAllLines(e.SAVE_DRIVE_Path, e.List2ToSave);
        File.WriteAllLines(e.SAVE_DRIVE_Letter, e.List1ToSave);

        Drive_text.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        drives_progres.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        drives_progres.IsIndeterminate = false;
    }
}
```

Now i do hope this would make some things more clear.

Comment: With data bound values you will usually clone state before editing it. This way you can easily undo/cancel edit. Use bindings and look into MVVM.

Comment: Though it looks like another "show progress" failed attempt. [Here](https://youtu.be/K2rywTFAEIA) is a tutorial using `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: So its not possible to do it like this? @Sinatr 
I had hoped to just change some Properties as soon something is finished. This is just a small APP, MVVM is a overkill ...

Funny thing is i can select these Properties in the intellisense von Visual Studio, and set the attributes without problems (errors).

Comment: You didn't show enough code to help you with specific problems, e.g. with double click or "not working" properties. Maybe you are changing properties for a wrong window? Maybe you not seeing changes (e.g. debugging a long synchronous method which can't update UI)?

Comment: how/from where is your custom event fired? Maybe there is a threading issue involved ... You might try to set the properties of the controls by [invoke on the dispatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke?view=net-5.0).

Comment: Hello again and i updated my code as you guys asked. @dba

Comment: @Sinatr Please look. I sure hope that it wont be necessary to transform my whole project into MVVM just to change few Properties ...

Comment: You don't unsubscribe from event. You rise event multiple times in the loop, while in event handled it seems you are finializing things (expecting just one call?), maybe rise event once at the end or create 2 events: to report progress and to finalize.